# Increasing derivatives of recursively defined polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, oeis

Consider recursively defined polynomials $f_0(x)=x$ and $f_{n+1}(x)=f_n(x)−f_n'(x) x (1−x)$.

These polynomials have some special properties, for example $f_n(0)=0$, $f_n(1)=1$, and all $n+1$ roots of $f_n$ are in $[0,1)$. Let $x_n$ denote the largest root of $f_n$. Then $f_n(x_n)=0$, and $f_n'(x_n)>0$. Moreover, $0=x_1 < x_2 < \dots < x_n < 1$.

I want to prove the following conjecture: $f_n'(x)>f_{n-1}'(x)$ for all $x \in [x_{n+1},1)$.

Some of the first polynomials are:

1. $f_1(x)=x^2$, $f_1'(x)=2x$, $x_1=0$
2. $f_2(x)=2 x^3−x^2$, $f_2'(x)=6 x^2−2$, $x_2=\frac{1}{2}$
3. $f_3(x)=6x^4−6x^3+x^2$, $f_3'(x)=24 x^3−18x^2+2x$, $x_3 \approx 0.7887$
4. $f_4(x)=24x^5−36x^4+14x^3−x^2$, $f_4'(x)=120x^4−144x^3+42x^2−2x$, $x_4 \approx 0.9082$
5. $f_5(x)=120 x^6-240 x^5+ 150 x^4-30 x^3 +x^2$, $f_5'(x) =720x^5-1200 x^4+600 x^3-90 x^2+ 2 x$, $x_5 = 0.9587$

Therefore

- $f_2'(x)−f_1'(x)=6x^2−4x \geq 0$ for all $x \geq \frac{2}{3}$. Note that, $x_2<\frac{2}{3} < x3$.
- $f_3'(x)−f_2'(x)=24 x^3−24x^2+4x \geq 0$ for all $x \geq 0.7887 = x_3 < x_4$.
- $f_4'(x)-f_3'(x)=120 x^4-168x^3+60 x^2-4x \geq 0$ for all $x \geq 0.8685 < x_5$

Comment: Note http://oeis.org/A019538.

Comment: This is interesting, although I'm not sure how to use this. I can confirm that the absolute polynomial coefficients in my sequence are indeed the same as the numbers in the triangle you referred. This is a curious fact. But the signs oscillate (the leading coefficient is always positive, the second one negative, etc). In fact, the leading coefficient is always $n!$ and the coefficient of $x^2$ is 1 of $n$ is odd and $-1$ if $n$ is even. Any pointers where I should look?

Comment: Just some potential leads. See also http://oeis.org/A133314 which is a refined signed array. You should be able to at least find an e.g.f. for your sequence, which might possibly be of help to you or others in finding an answer.

Comment: A potential e.g.f. is $\frac{x}{1-x (1-e^{-t})}$.

Comment: So the e.g.f. for the derivatives would be $\frac{1}{[1-x (1-e^{-t})]^2}$.

Comment: This looks useful, but my knowledge of discrete mathematics is not deep enough. Could you recommend a good reference where I could learn more about this stuff, especially the relationships between generating functions and polynomials?

Comment: Wilf's [generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html)

Comment: Wilf is good. The e.g.f. for the differences of the derivatives is $\frac{1-x (1+e^{-t})}{[1-x (1-e^{-t})]^3} = 2x - 1 + (6x^2 - 4x) t + (24x^3-24x^2+4x) \frac{t^2}{2!}+ \cdots$.

Comment: Perhaps the Liu and Wang ref in A0019538, which deals with such types of recursions, provides some clues.

Comment: Two additional observations: (1) coefficients of the polynomials can be computed as $S_n^k (-1)^{n-k} k! = \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{n-j} {k \choose j} j^n$ (where $S_n^k$ is the Stirling number of the second kind). (2) [Liu-Wang](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0509207) or even more directly [Dominicia-Driverb-Jordaanc](https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.0041) apply almost directly here, i.e. their methods could be used to show that all roots are real and interlaced. But I don't think that they have results that connect roots of higher polynomials to derivatives of lower polynomials.